# How can I partially reveal and partially fill color in image

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiimage

In my project I'm displaying image like this,

[image]

But according to user progress I want to hide the partial image.

**Example** :  If user process is 75% than my image will display like this,

[image]

One idea is that I will use some variation of image and show image according to the percentage. But if I can achieve this programmatically with one image than it will be better. plz help for this problem.

Comment: I would test it with CISwipeTransition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys i have done it using this code :

```
 UIImage * flagImage = [UIImage imageNamed:flagImageStr];  //this is image of the flag
    UIImage * maskImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mask4.png"];  //Created heart shape mask image

    UIImage *image = [self maskImage:flagImage withMask:maskImg];
    CALayer *layer = partialFlagIV.layer;  //partialFlagIV is my imageview name
    layer.shadowOpacity = .9;
    layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,0);
    layer.shadowRadius = 2;

    partialFlagIV.image = image;

    int percentage = [percentageStr integerValue];  //percentageStr value will decide how much part of image will be in other color
    int percentageValue = 100-percentage;

    int maskImgYValue = (percentageValue*80)/100;
    int imgYvalue;
    if (percentageValue<40) {
        imgYvalue = 305-(maskImgYValue*4);
    }else{
        imgYvalue = 305-(maskImgYValue*3.8);
    }

//This code is needed when i use app in iPad bcoze of size of partialFlagIV is larger in iPad
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        int baseValue = 80+(percentage*0.2);
        percentage = baseValue-percentage;
        maskImgYValue = maskImgYValue+percentage;
    }


    UIImageView *aImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(partialFlagIV.frame.origin.x, partialFlagIV.frame.origin.y, partialFlagIV.frame.size.width,maskImgYValue)];  //created another imageview to place it on the partialFlagIV so it will display like color field in partialFlagIV 


    aImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    image = [self imageByCropping:image toRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height-imgYvalue)];  //this method is used to crop my flage image

    aImageView.image = [self newImageFromMaskImage:image  inColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(186/255.0) green:(57/255.0) blue:(38/255.0) alpha:1]];   //this method will create mask image with given color
    [self.view addSubview:aImageView];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:aImageView];

//this method will crop the flag imge to heart shape
-(UIImage *)imageByCropping:(UIImage *)imageToCrop toRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([imageToCrop CGImage], rect);

    UIImage *cropped = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);

    return cropped;
}

//this method will create color image using mask image
-(UIImage *) newImageFromMaskImage:(UIImage *)mask inColor:(UIColor *) color {
    CGImageRef maskImage = mask.CGImage;
    CGFloat width = mask.size.width;
    CGFloat height = mask.size.height;
    CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(0,0,width,height);

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef bitmapContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, width, height, 8, 0, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
    CGContextClipToMask(bitmapContext, bounds, maskImage);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(bitmapContext, color.CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(bitmapContext, bounds);

    CGImageRef mainViewContentBitmapContext = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmapContext);
    CGContextRelease(bitmapContext);

    UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:mainViewContentBitmapContext];
    return result;
}
```

Added comment to explain codes.Hope it help future user.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is image masking. From [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_images/dq_images.html) -

> An image mask is a bitmap that specifies an area to paint, but not the
>   color. In effect, an image mask acts as a stencil to specify where to
>   place color on the page. Quartz uses the current fill color to paint
>   an image mask.

So as your percentage of download increases you decrease the alpha value of the `uiimage` below. Hope this is what you require.

Comment: Yes my second idea is to use this mask. for that i have seen this link `http://jeroendeleeuw.com/post/33638733049/how-to-mask-images-with-core-graphics-in-ios` but still not sure how to add it in my situation.